# The most efficient way to enable a button if the correct radio-buttons are selected?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, button, radio-button

New to javascript here.  I have a form with a series of "Yes/No" radio buttons and I tried making a function to disable the "Submit Form" button if the radio buttons are either, at anytime:

1. If one or more radio buttons are not actively selected
2. If one or more radio buttons have 'No' is selected

If all 4 radio buttons have 'Yes' is selected then the 'Submit Form' button should be enabled `disabled=false`.

I'm really trying to understand but I don't think I'm achieving the effect I want.

I must use javascript only (I'll be learning jQuery later on) for this.  Any help for me to understand would be appreciated.

Thank you.

```js
function Check(e) {
  var button = document.getElementById("submit");

  if (button.disabled == true) {
    button.disabled = false;
  } else {
    button.disabled = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="datetime-local">
  <br>

  <input name="Q1" type="radio" value="yes" onclick="Check(this)" required>Yes
  <input name="Q1" type="radio" value="no" required>No
  <br>

  <input name="Q2" type="radio" value="yes" onclick="Check(this)" required>Yes
  <input name="Q2" type="radio" value="no" required>No
  <br>

  <input name="Q3" type="radio" value="yes" onclick="Check(this)" required>Yes
  <input name="Q3" type="radio" value="no" required>No
  <br>

  <input name="Q4" type="radio" value="yes" onclick="Check(this)" required>Yes
  <input name="Q4" type="radio" value="no" required>No
  <br>

  <button id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" disabled>
    SUBMIT FORM
  </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if the lenght of the *no* `checked` is superior from zero or no radio checked, check the working example below.

Hope this helps.

```js
function Check(el) {
  var button = document.getElementById("submit");

  var nbr_of_checked_no = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio][value=no]:checked').length;
  var nbr_checked_radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]:checked').length;

  /*
     'nbr_of_checked_no>0' : mean if at least one of the 'no' options checked
     'nbr_checked_radios==0' : mean if no radio button is checked 
  */
  if (nbr_of_checked_no>0 || nbr_checked_radios<4) {
    button.disabled = true;
  } else {
    button.disabled = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input name="Q1" type="radio" value="yes" onclick="Check(this)" required>Yes
  <input name="Q1" type="radio" value="no"  onclick="Check(this)"required>No
  <br>

  <input name="Q2" type="radio" value="yes" onclick="Check(this)" required>Yes
  <input name="Q2" type="radio" value="no"  onclick="Check(this)"required>No
  <br>

  <input name="Q3" type="radio" value="yes" onclick="Check(this)" required>Yes
  <input name="Q3" type="radio" value="no"  onclick="Check(this)"required>No
  <br>

  <input name="Q4" type="radio" value="yes" onclick="Check(this)" required>Yes
  <input name="Q4" type="radio" value="no"  onclick="Check(this)" required>No
  <br>

  <button id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" disabled>
    SUBMIT FORM
  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Is there a way to prevent the submit button being enabled so fast if only one radio-button was selected and the others are left non-selected?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, please try to clarify more.

Comment: For example, when the form loads and the user clicks any one of the 'Yes' radio button, the button is automatically enabled even though the other 3 radio buttons haven't been filled yet... is there a way to disable the submit button until all 4 radio buttons have "yes" selected?

Answer (score 0):

Another (ES6) approach. This way you don't have to work with inline clickhandlers and you have a nice separation of concerns. You can also execute the `checkIfBtnShouldBeEnabled()` on the page load if you want.

```
const submit = document.getElementById('submit');
const allRadios = document.querySelectorAll('.your-form input[type="radio"]');

function checkIfBtnShouldBeEnabled() {
  let enabled = true;
  const yesRadios = document.querySelectorAll('.your-form input[type="radio"][value="yes"]');

  yesRadios.forEach(radio => {        
    if (!radio.checked){
      enabled = false;
      return false;
    }
  });

  submit.disabled = enabled ? false : true;
}

allRadios.forEach(radio => {
  radio.addEventListener('change', checkIfBtnShouldBeEnabled);
});
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qqXdOO